# when I press sculpting, it wont show the options

Tags: modeling, sculpting, error

[image: The issue]

can you help me bring back the sidebar?

Comment: Hello and welcome, you need to explain more what you mean. From your image, it does not look that you are in sculpting mode, you are in object mode (left upper corner)

Answer (score 2):

What you have clicked on is one of the predesigned workspaces, i.e. a window layout which is supposed to be helpful for a certain task.

You have to change to a different *object interaction mode*, which you can do with the dropdown menu in the top left where it says *Object Mode*. Click there to switch to *Sculpt Mode*.

Some of those workspaces switch the interaction mode automatically when you choose them, and so does the *Sculpting* layout usually. But you need to have an object selected which you want to sculpt in order to have the mode automatically enabled.

And this means a mesh object which can be sculpted. If you have any other type object selected (or if nothing is selected then the one that was selected last) like a camera, a light, a curve etc. then it won't switch to *Sculpt Mode* either.

[image: interaction vs workspace]